# Non latin character sets in domain names, Millenium Bug 2.0?

Tags: internationalization

I understand the cultural diversity motivation behind this ICAN decision but how disruptive is the change going to be?

How many routers will choke on non latin characters in URLs?

And what about the millions of lines of business application code handling email fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry much about the email thing yet... Most email services don't stick to email address specs anyways. For example, "This is me"@[10.11.12.13] is a valid email address according to the standard. Its another thing that people don't actually use this format. Similarly, non-latin chars won't be a problem till people actually start using them - and that may take some time.

Routers won't choke, like paxdiablo mentioned, Probably DNS servers won't either. But things like proxy servers just *might* fail initally, atleast till websites actually start using them.

But the main problem I feel is with usability. How do users who don't have non-latin characters on their keyboard type in the address correctly? They might not be interested in adding a new keyboard layout (via software of course) just to type in a URL. Also, with asian languages and all, its quite hard getting the characters right for people who don't know that language - with complex glyphs and all. So the only alternative, according to me, atleast for now, would be that there are latin alternatives or aliases to all these domain names and email addresses.

Comment: @Rase "Similarly, non-latin chars won't be a problem till people actually start using them - and that may take some time". Hmmm not so sure, the global hacker community will have a field day working out which bits of internet infrastructure or online services crash on receipt of a non latin email address.

Comment: Nothing stops a hacker from doint just that right now. If there are services in use that crash on that kind of input, they are already vulnerable.

Comment: Well, true I guess... But I don't think hackers will get anywhere with this thing coming in now. If there is a problem when you send non-latin chars to web server, the problem is already there. If existing web servers or email servers can be compromised or broken by sending them non-latin characters, they already can be. So, hackers, or rather crackers, don't have to wait till somebody tells them its legal to use non-latin now. It will only be a revelation to an already existing problem. My guess is many current mailing systems will reject the addresses, and that will be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to worry about routers. They route packets between IP addresses, not DNS names. And the millions of lines of business logic will still be able to handle Latin characters, they're not going to break overnight. That's because the data entry fields for email names should already be filtering out non-Latin stuff (if it's not, they deserve everything they get).

Granted, they may need changes to allow non-Latin URLs to be entered but that's a management issue and vastly different to Y2K, where applications were expected to stop working.

*Aside:* most Y2K (financial) applications were fixed well in advance simply because they work with dates multiple years into the future anyway. For all the money a major telco spent on Y2K, we found *one* problem and that was a web page listing the date as Jan 1, 19100 (because some clown didn't realize that a `tm_year` was number of years since 1900, not just the last two digits of the year).

I suspect this issue will have even *less* impact than Y2K.

Comment: @paxdiablo - Good points but what about url rewriting logic, reverse DNS look up, desk top security software and all the gazilion of database fields that should be nvarchar() and not varchar? I still think this is a big issue and we developers need to have an answer prepared before the press sniff a scare story.

Comment: The *press* got the rear ends handed to them on a platter over Y2K. Did one plane fall out of the sky? Did one nuke power station go up in smoke? I couldn't care less about a scare story, that sort of stuff keeps me employed :-) Yes the applications you mention may break with non-Latin characters but I can't see *anything* in your list that's going to bring down the net. The problems will be fixed as they always are. That's what we do (Y2K, non-Latin chars, or just the bug of the day in whatever program you support).

Comment: @paxdiablo "a scare story, that sort of stuff keeps me employed". Well indeed, my first thought this morning was thank you ICAN, this is just what a moribund global economy needs :-)